# Connection reset by peer: socket write error during ftp

Tags: sockets, ftp, ioexception, socketexception

While trying to ftp (with implicit ssl) a file to a server, I consistently get a 'Connection Reset By Peer: Socket Write Error' or abnormally a 'Connection Aborted By Software' error. The file is uploaded to the server, but is completely empty. However, after setting up a local test ftp server, I upload files to that server with no issue. Could these errors be cause by some type of firewall? If not, is there another issue. If it is, can anything in the code be changed to fix it?

Using Apache Commons:

```
String SFTPHOST = compParam.getSftpHostNme();
int SFTPPORT = 990;
String SFTPUSER = compParam.getSftpLogin();
String SFTPPASS = compParam.getSftpPassword();
            FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient(true);
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        if(!ftpClient.login(SFTPUSER, SFTPPASS)){
            SwingUtils.showMessage(this, "Error: Trouble Connecting \n" + "User Name and Password or Host is incorrect \n"
                    + "or someone else is using these credentials");
            return;
        }
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);

        File f = new File(TLCTripRecordExportDlg.filePath + TLCTripRecordExportDlg.fileName);

        String remoteFile = TLCTripRecordExportDlg.fileName;
  FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
  ProgressMonitorInputStream pmiStream = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(this,"Uploading the File",inputStream);
//      OutputStream os = ftpClient.storeFileStream(remoteFile);
//      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
//      int len;
//      while ((len = pmiStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
//      {
//          os.write(buffer, 0, len);
//          os.flush();
//      }
//      pmiStream.close();
//      os.close();


  if(ftpClient.storeFile(remoteFile, pmiStream)){
    inputStream.close();
    pmiStream.close();
  }else{

    SwingUtils.showMessage(this, "File Not Uploaded: " + ftpClient.getReplyString());
    return;
  }
```

The error is thrown at store file. Here's the stack trace:

```
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.limosys.gui.job.TLCTripUploadDlg.upload_actionPerformed(TLCTripUploadDlg.java:261)
    at com.limosys.gui.job.TLCTripUploadDlg$3.actionPerformed(TLCTripUploadDlg.java:193)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6055)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4653)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4236)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4166)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2482)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:648)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:607)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:605)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:621)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:619)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:618)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:178)
    at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1044)
    at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Dialog.java:1096)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1094)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1584)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1536)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:841)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:984)
    at com.limosys.gui.dialogs.gen.GenDialog.setVisible(GenDialog.java:250)
    at com.limosys.gui.job.TLCTripUploadDlg.showIt(TLCTripUploadDlg.java:325)
    at com.limosys.gui.job.TLCTripExport$ExportTLCTripTask.invoke(TLCTripExport.java:363)
    at com.limosys.dblib.utils.JLimoWorker$1.run(JLimoWorker.java:169)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:646)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:607)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:605)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Add these two lines:

```
        ftpClient.execPROT("P");
        ftpClient.execPBSZ(0);
```